# SEGMENTATION FAULT in PERL SCRIPT on unix in multi-process/threads using pipes

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl, multiprocessing, interprocess

I'm new to the process of Multi-process programming in perl. I am trying to write a multi-threaded multi-process based application which is giving me "SEGMENTATION FAULT".
The program is simple. First the PARENT PROCESS spawns a few processes (using fork) and each of the process runs after sometime and dies after a random delay.
The parent process in the meantime, spawns equal number of threads to listen to each of the newly forked child processes.
I am using pipes to communicate between the forked processes and the threads spawned from the main process.
The idea here is that when a process dies, another new process should be immediately spawned with the same pipes and therefore the infinite while loop after the subroutine calls.
For sometime, this works correctly, but then suddenly there is a segmentation fault.
How do I debug such a scenario ?
MY PERL VERSION IS 5.8.8

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use IO::Pipe;
use warnings;
print "Starting main program\n";
my $ACTIVE_PROCESSES :shared =0;
my $MAX_PROCESSES:shared =5,
my %process_state_list : shared;
my %process_id_list : shared;
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { wait };
my $GLOBAL_COUNT=0;
my @pipe_array=&share([]);
&init_pipes();
&spawn_process();
while(1)
{
for (my $i=0;$i<$MAX_PROCESSES;$i++)
 {
    if ($process_state_list{$i} =~ /INACTIVE/)
    {
        print "Found Process $i is inactive\n"; 
    spawn_next_process($i);
    }
 }
}
print "End of main program from $$\n";

sub init_pipes
{
my $i=0;
for ($i=0;$i< $MAX_PROCESSES; $i++)
  { 
    $pipe_array[$i] = IO::Pipe->new();
    $process_state_list{$i}="INACTIVE";
    print "Pipe $i initialized to $pipe_array[$i]\n";
  }
}
sub spawn_process
{
print "Spawn process called..\n";
while ( $ACTIVE_PROCESSES < $MAX_PROCESSES) 
   {
      $GLOBAL_COUNT++;
      PARENT_create_child();
      PARENT_create_child_listener();
   }
}

sub PARENT_update_child_map
{
my ($i,$cmd)=@_;
if ($cmd =~ /CREATE/)
  {
    for (my $j=0;$j<$MAX_PROCESSES;$j++)
    {
        print "j is $j and process_state_list is $process_state_list{$j}\n";
    if ($process_state_list{$j}=~ /INACTIVE/)
    {
        $process_state_list{$j}="ACTIVE";
        return $j;
    }
    }
  }
}
sub PARENT_create_child()
{
    for (my $i=0;$i<$MAX_PROCESSES;$i++)
     {
        print"--------FORKING CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID $$\n";
        my $local_pr_id = PARENT_update_child_map($i,"CREATE");
        my $pid = fork() ;
                if ($pid) {
        # parent
        print "For local_pr_id $local_pr_id CHILD is $pid, PARENT $$\n";
        $ACTIVE_PROCESSES++;
                } 
        elsif ($pid == 0) {
                # child
                child_activator($local_pr_id);
        exit 0;
        } else {
                die "couldnt fork: $!\n";
        }
      }
}
sub PARENT_create_child_listener()
{
print"--------THREADING CHILD LISTENER FROM--$$--\n";
my $i;
for ($i=0;$i<$MAX_PROCESSES;$i++)
{
my $worker_thread = threads->create(sub {\&read_from_child($i)});
$worker_thread->detach();
}
}
sub read_from_child
{
    my $th=threads->self();
    print"--------NOW THREADING:$th->tid()\n";
    my ($pipe_index)=shift;
    print "pipe_index is $pipe_index\n";
    ($pipe_array[$pipe_index])->reader();
    my $filehandle=$pipe_array[$pipe_index];
    while ( <$filehandle> ) {
        my $msg=$_;
        print "CHILD LISTENER received: $msg And current Process ID is $$\n";
        PARENT_msg_from_child($msg);
    }
    print "Exiting read_from_child from $$\n";
}
sub PARENT_msg_from_child()
{
my $msg=shift;
if ($msg =~ /IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT/)
  {
   PARENT_handle_IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT($msg);
  }
if ($msg=~ /IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START/)
  {
   PARENT_handle_IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START($msg);
  }
}
sub PARENT_handle_IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START
{
my $msg=shift;
my @split_array=split(":",$msg);
my $local_pr_id=$split_array[1];
my $process_id=$split_array[2];
$process_state_list{$local_pr_id}="ACTIVE";
$process_id_list{$local_pr_id}=$process_id;
}
sub PARENT_handle_IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT
{
my $msg=shift;
my @split_array=split(":",$msg);
my $local_pr_id=$split_array[1];
print "------------------------\n";
$ACTIVE_PROCESSES--;
$process_state_list{$local_pr_id}="INACTIVE";
my $exists = kill 0, $local_pr_id;
kill(9,$process_id_list{$local_pr_id}) if $exists;
print "Process $process_id_list{$local_pr_id} terminated\n";
}
sub spawn_next_process
{
my $local_pr_id= shift;
print"--------FORKING NEXT CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID $$\n";
        $process_state_list{$local_pr_id}="ACTIVE";
        my $pid = fork() ;
                if ($pid) {
        # parent
        print "For local_pr_id $local_pr_id CHILD is $pid, PARENT $$\n";
        $ACTIVE_PROCESSES++;
                } 
        elsif ($pid == 0) {
                # child
                child_activator($local_pr_id);
        exit 0;
        } else {
                die "couldnt fork: $!\n";
        }
}
#################C H I L D -- S E C T I O N####################
sub child_activator {
        sleep (7);
        my $local_pr_id=shift;
        print "In child activator $$\n";
        my $filehandle=$pipe_array[$local_pr_id] ;
        ($pipe_array[$local_pr_id])->writer();
        my $message="IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START:$local_pr_id:$$:";
    print "Sending $message\n";
        print $filehandle $message
            or die "Failed to pass message to child: $!";
        my $random_number = rand();
        sleep(4*$random_number);
        print "Now in child process $$\n";
        print "local_pr_id is $local_pr_id\n";
        $message="IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT:$local_pr_id:";
        print "Sending $message\n";
        print $filehandle $message
            or die "Failed to pass message to child: $!";
}
################# E N D - C H I L D - S E C T I O N###########
```

**THE OUTPUT I GET FROM THIS IS VERY WEIRED** :-

```
<I>xl-mat-02{userxxx}141: perl run_tc.pl
Starting main program
Pipe 0 initialized to IO::Pipe=GLOB(0x169c4830)
Pipe 1 initialized to IO::Pipe=GLOB(0x168632a0)
Pipe 2 initialized to IO::Pipe=GLOB(0x169c4af0)
Pipe 3 initialized to IO::Pipe=GLOB(0x169c4bb0)
Pipe 4 initialized to IO::Pipe=GLOB(0x169c4c70)
Spawn process called..
--------FORKING CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID 1520
j is 0 and process_state_list is INACTIVE
For local_pr_id 0 CHILD is 1598, PARENT 1520
--------FORKING CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID 1520
j is 0 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 1 and process_state_list is INACTIVE
For local_pr_id 1 CHILD is 1599, PARENT 1520
--------FORKING CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID 1520
j is 0 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 1 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 2 and process_state_list is INACTIVE
For local_pr_id 2 CHILD is 1600, PARENT 1520
--------FORKING CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID 1520
j is 0 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 1 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 2 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 3 and process_state_list is INACTIVE
For local_pr_id 3 CHILD is 1601, PARENT 1520
--------FORKING CHILD from MAIN PROCESS MAIN PID 1520
j is 0 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 1 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 2 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 3 and process_state_list is ACTIVE
j is 4 and process_state_list is INACTIVE
For local_pr_id 4 CHILD is 1602, PARENT 1520
--------THREADING CHILD LISTENER FROM--1520--
--------NOW THREADING:threads=SCALAR(0x16abfef0)->tid()
pipe_index is 0
--------NOW THREADING:threads=SCALAR(0x16b95010)->tid()
pipe_index is 1
--------NOW THREADING:threads=SCALAR(0x2aaaac0fdfb0)->tid()
pipe_index is 2
--------NOW THREADING:threads=SCALAR(0x2aaaac1e2770)->tid()
pipe_index is 3
--------NOW THREADING:threads=SCALAR(0x2aaaac2c7210)->tid()
pipe_index is 4
In child activator 1598
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START:0:1598:
In child activator 1599
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START:1:1599:
In child activator 1600
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START:2:1600:
In child activator 1601
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START:3:1601:
In child activator 1602
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_START:4:1602:
Now in child process 1599
local_pr_id is 1
Now in child process 1600
local_pr_id is 2
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT:2:
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT:1:
Now in child process 1601
local_pr_id is 3
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT:3:
***Segmentation fault***
xl-mat-02{userxxx}142: Now in child process 1598
local_pr_id is 0
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT:0:
Now in child process 1602
local_pr_id is 4
Sending IPC_MSG_PROCESS_EXIT:4:</I>
```

I am unable to spot why segementation fault is coming.
Like i said, i'm new to programing in multi process env. so I might have missed something very basic.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Even if you have some basic tips for segmentation faults in such a scenario, please do let me know, because I am clueless !

Comment: You shouldn't get a segfault even if you do something wrong. It would indicate a bug in Perl or in an XS module. What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: To debug `perl`, you'd use `gdb --args perl script.pl`. Entering `bt` gives a backtrace...

Comment: PERL VERSION IS 5.8.8.

Comment: That version is over a decade old, and it's not even the most recent release of 5.8. Countless bugs have been fixed since. It's no longer supported (and neither is 5.10 or 5.12, and 5.14 will only be supported until 5.18 comes out in a month or so). Use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to install a newer Perl locally.

Comment: Thanks ikegami. Thanks for the update. I tried it on 5.8.14 and it disappeared, though my perl script is far from acheiving what it was supposed to do.

Comment: (5.8 only goes to 5.8.9. You probably meant 5.14)

Comment: Yes..of course, its 5.14

Comment: To clarify what @ikegami means by "no longer supported", new stable releases of those major versions will no longer be released. There won't be a 5.8.10 nor 5.10.2 nor 5.12.5. However, they will continue to be usable for a long time to come. That said, if you can use the latest Perl you should.  And if you're using threads you want to use the most recent Perl possible.